# Integral $\int_0^1 \log \Gamma(x)\cos (2\pi n x)\, dx=\frac{1}{4n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

$$
I:=\int_0^1 \log \Gamma(x)\cos (2\pi n x)\, dx=\frac{1}{4n}.
$$
Thank you.
The Gamma function is given by $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ and its integral representation is $$
\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-t}\, dt.
$$
If we write the gamma function as an integral we end up with a more complicated double integral.  And I am not too equipped with tools for dealing with gamma functions inside integrals.

We can possibly try
$$
\Re\bigg[\int_0^1 \log \Gamma(x)e^{2\pi i n x}\, dx\bigg]=\frac{1}{4n}.
$$
but I still do not where to go from here. 
Thanks.

Comment: Where $n>0$ and an integer, presumably. For $n=0$, 
$$
\int_0^1  \ln \Gamma(z) \ \mathrm{d}z = \frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi
$$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$\log\Gamma(x)=(\frac12-x)(\gamma+\log 2)+(1-x)\log\pi-\frac12\log\sin\pi x+\frac1\pi\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{\log k\sin (2\pi kx)}{k}$$

Exploiting the orthogonality of $\{\sin(2n \pi x),\cos(2n\pi x)\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ on $[0,1]$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
I&=\int^1_0\log\Gamma(x)\cos(2n\pi x)dx\\
&=-\frac12\int^1_0\log(\sin(\pi x))\cos(2n\pi x)dx\\
&=-\frac1{4n\pi}\int^1_0\log(\sin(\pi x))d(\sin(2n\pi x))\\
&=\frac1{4n\pi}\int^1_0\sin(2n\pi x)d(\log(\sin(\pi x)))\\
&=\frac1{4n}\int^1_0\sin(2n\pi x)\cot(\pi x)dx\\
&=\frac1{4n}\int^1_0\frac{\sin(2n\pi x)}{\sin (\pi x)}\cos(\pi x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2n}\int^1_0\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos((2k-1)\pi x)\right)\cos(\pi x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2n}\int^1_0\cos^2(\pi x)dx\\
&=\frac1{4n}.
\end{align*}$$

Edit:
$$\begin{align*}
\int^1_0x\cos(2\pi n x)dx&=\frac12\left(\int^1_0x\cos(2\pi n x)dx+\int^1_0(1-x)\cos(2\pi n (1-x))dx\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\int^1_0x\cos(2\pi n x)dx+\int^1_0(1-x)\cos(2\pi n x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac12\int^1_0\cos(2\pi n x)dx\\
&=0 \text{ for }n\in\mathbb{Z}^+.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: You are very good.  Thank you Chen Wang for  your clever solutions

Comment: You appeal to the orthogonality of the Fourier basis functions to disregard terms. It is not obvious to me that you can disregard the $x$ terms. I haven't thought carefully about this but it seems to me since the Fourier series of $x$ is nontrivial it should in fact matter.

Comment: @nayrb if its not broken, don't fix it :)

Comment: @Integrals, but it *is* potentially broken. At the very least it is lacking detail.

Comment: Actually, $\int_0^1 (ax+b) \cos(2n\pi x) \mathrm{d}x=0$ for $n>0$. So except for the case $n=0$, it looks good. For the $x$ alone, remember it's an odd function.

Answer (score 25):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{I \equiv \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x}}\cos\pars{2\pi n x}\,\dd x
     ={1 \over 4n}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> I&=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{1 - x}\sin\pars{\pi x}}
> \cos\pars{2\pi n x}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&=\ln\pars{\pi}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\cos\pars{2\pi nx}\,\dd x}
> ^{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{0}}}\ -\ \overbrace{%
> \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{x}}\cos\pars{2\pi n\bracks{1 - x}}\,\dd x}
> ^{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{I}}}
> \\[5mm]&-{1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\cos\pars{2nx}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
I&=-\,{1 \over 2\pi}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\cos\pars{2nx}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{-\,{\pi \over 2n}}}
=\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 4n}}
\end{align}

Comment: Very beautiful solution!

Comment: Nice solution. Much more elegant than mine.

Comment: Very nice thanks Felix!+1

Comment: **WOW !** Just wow !