# Justify $\zeta(3)=2\int_0^1 \left(Li_2(e^{-2\pi i x})+Li_2(e^{2\pi i x}\right))\log \Gamma(x)dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, polylogarithm

I don't know if this approach to get a formula involving the **Apéry constant** was in the literature. This idea was a simple idea few minutes ago, when I was studying the answers in this site **Math Stack Exchange** for the question [Integral $\int_0^1 \log \Gamma(x)\cos (2\pi n x)\, dx=\frac{1}{4n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782977/integral-int-01-log-gammax-cos-2-pi-n-x-dx-frac14n?rq=1).

One has that since **Wolfram Alpha** said that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos (2 \pi k x)}{k^2}=\frac{Li_2(e^{-2\pi i x})+Li_2(e^{2\pi i x})}{2},$$ 
where $Li_s(z)$ is the **polylogarithm function**. Then using the **dominated convergence theorem** we should have 
then $$\zeta(3)=2\int_0^1  \left(Li_2(e^{-2\pi i x})+Li_2(e^{2\pi i x}\right))\log \Gamma(x)dx .$$

> **Question.** Please can you justify all these claims to provide us this nice exercise for this site Mathematics Stack Exchange? I say justify the closed-form for the series involving the cosine function (if you find a reference in this site, only is required add it) and after jusfity how one uses the dominated convergence theorem. **Thanks in advance.**

With respect the use of the theorem, I know that I can bound the cosine function, but how can one bounds  $|\log \Gamma(x) |$ for $0<x<1$?

You can see the calculation from the [online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) with this code

> *int_0^1 log (Gamma(x))2(Li_2(e^(-2 i pi x))+Li_2(e^(2 i pi x)))dx*.

Notice that the imaginary part is $\approx 0$.

Comment: Perhps if some user has abilities and the calculations are feasibles, can thinks as homework what's about iterated integrals of this kind, I say the integral from the referenced post, since one has for example $(\int_0^1)^2=\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{n^2}$, and I don't know if it is possible do more calculations when one consider $(\int_0^1)^2$ as a double integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1 dx dy$

Comment: Thanks for previous vote up. Now I know that perhaps have no  mathematical meaning my words about the bound for **the logarithmic of the gamma function**, since **does not depend on** $n$. In any case, **please justify the use of a theorem to swap the integral sign with the series**. I know that previous cosine functions have sign in the interval $[0,1]$. Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we have to prove that
$$ \frac{\zeta(3)}{4} = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2\pi k x)}{k^2}\log\Gamma(x)\,dx $$
but over the iterval $(0,1)$ the graph of the Fourier cosine series $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2\pi k x)}{k^2}$ is just the graph of a parabola, since $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi k x)}{k}$ is a sawtooth wave. Moreover, such a parabola is symmetric with respect to the point $x=\frac{1}{2}$. The claim boils down to:
$$ \frac{\zeta(3)}{4} = \int_{0}^{1/2}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\pi^2(x-x^2)\right)\log\left(\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)\right)\,dx $$
or, through the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function and the substitution $x\to\frac{1}{2}-x$:
$$ \frac{\zeta(3)}{4}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\int_{0}^{1/2}(12x^2-1)\log\left(\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi x)}\right)\,dx$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ 3\zeta(3)=\pi^2\int_{0}^{1/2}(1-12x^2)\log(\cos(\pi x))\,dx \tag{1a}$$
or to:
$$ \frac{3\zeta(3)}{\pi^3} = \int_{0}^{1/2}\tan(\pi x)(x-4x^3)\,dx,\tag{1b}$$
$$ \frac{\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\pi}{2}\cot(\pi x/2)x(x-1)(x-2)\,dx.\tag{1c}$$
Since the Weierstrass product of the cosine function gives
$$ \cos(\pi x)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4 x^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)\tag{2}$$
and
$$ \int_{0}^{1/2}(1-12x^2)\log\left(1-\frac{4 x^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)\,dx \\= \frac{1}{3}+4 n (1+n)+2 n (1+n) (1+2 n) (\log(n)-\log(n+1)) \tag{3}$$
the whole question boils down to an exercise in summation by parts involving the derivative of the $\zeta$ function (in particular, $\zeta'(-2)$, that is related with $\zeta(3)$ via the [reflection formula for the $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)). As an alternative, $(1)$ can be checked by expanding both $12x^2-1$ and [$\log\cos(\pi x)$ as Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos). On the other hand, Chen Wang's solution to the linked question just relies on [Kummer's Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Fourier_series_expansion) for $\log\Gamma$. The Weierstrass product also provides the identities
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{x-2n}+\frac{1}{x+2n}\right) \tag{4}$$
$$ \tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x}{(2n+1)^2-x^2} \tag{5} $$
that can be used to directly tackle $(1b)$ or $(1c)$.

---

Now we have a situation that often occurs in mathematics: when proving something, we go through some lemma that is crucial for other situations. In this case we have that the RHS of $(3)$ is summable over $n\geq 1$, so the "smallness" of such term gives us that
$$ \frac{4n(n+1)+\frac{1}{3}}{2n(2n+1)(n+1)} $$
is an excellent approximation of $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for any $n\geq 1$, and we may even estimate the error by approximating the associated integral with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, integration by parts or other techniques. In our case we get that the approximation error is less than $1.3\cdot 10^{-3}$ for any $n\geq 1$, and 
$$ \log(2)\approx\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2. $$

Comment: +1. Nice job. At the beginning 'Sowe' must be 'So we'. The sum of $\,\mathrm{Li}_{2}$'s is $2\pi^{2}\,\mathrm{B}_{2}(x) = 2\pi^{2}\left(\,x^{2} - x + 1/6\, \right)$ such that you can save some steps. As usual, it's a wonderful answer.

Comment: Seems a PhD thesis about my problem. Very thanks much for all details and references, and all topics. Is the best answer possible.

Comment: Many thanks also @FelixMarin

Answer (score 0):

Comment : from here http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFuncti ... owAll.html We know that $$\displaystyle{L{i_2}\left( z \right) + L{i_2}\left( {\frac{1}{z}} \right) =  - \frac{1}{2}{\log ^2}\left( { - z} \right) - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{6}} ,$$

Consequently $$\displaystyle{L{i_2}\left( {{e^{ - 2i\pi x}}} \right) + L{i_2}\left( {{e^{2i\pi x}}} \right) =  - \frac{1}{2}{\log ^2}\left( { - {e^{2i\pi x}}} \right) - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{6}}$$

$$\displaystyle{S = 2\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {L{i_2}\left( {{e^{ - 2i\pi x}}} \right) + L{i_2}\left( {{e^{2i\pi x}}} \right)} \right)\log \left( {\Gamma \left( x \right)} \right)dx}  = }$$ $$\displaystyle{2\int\limits_0^1 {\left( { - \frac{1}{2}{{\log }^2}\left( { - {e^{2i\pi x}}} \right) - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{6}} \right)\log \left( {\Gamma \left( x \right)} \right)dx}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \int\limits_0^1 {\left( { - {{\log }^2}\left( {{e^{i\pi \left( {2x - 1} \right)}}} \right) - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\Gamma \left( x \right)} \right)dx}  = \int\limits_0^1 {\left( { - {{\left( {i\pi \left( {2x - 1} \right)} \right)}^2} - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\Gamma \left( x \right)} \right)dx}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{\pi ^2}{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\Gamma \left( x \right)} \right)dx}  = {\pi ^2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\Gamma \left( x \right)} \right)dx} \mathop { =  =  =  = }\limits^{x \to 1 - x} }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = {\pi ^2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\Gamma \left( {1 - x} \right)} \right)dx}  \Rightarrow 2S = }$$ $$\displaystyle{{\pi ^2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\left( {\log \left( {\Gamma \left( {1 - x} \right)} \right) + \log \left( {\Gamma \left( x \right)} \right)} \right)dx}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = {\pi ^2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\Gamma \left( x \right)\Gamma \left( {1 - x} \right)} \right)dx}  = {\pi ^2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\frac{\pi }{{\sin \pi x}}} \right)dx}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = {\pi ^2}\log \left( \pi  \right)\underbrace {\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)dx} }_{ = 0} - {\pi ^2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\sin \pi x} \right)dx} }$$
$>\displaystyle{ =  - {\pi ^2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\sin \pi x} \right)dx} }$$

Then $$\displaystyle{S =  - \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\log \left( {\sin \pi x} \right)dx} }.$$ But $$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos nx}}{n}}  =  - \log 2 - \log \left( {\sin \frac{x}{2}} \right)}$$ (it turned out multiple times)

so $$\displaystyle{\log \left( {\sin \pi x} \right) =  - \log 2 - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos 2n\pi x}}{n}} }.$$ Consequently
$$\displaystyle{S = \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{2}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\left( {\log 2 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos 2n\pi x}}{n}} } \right)dx}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{2}\log 2\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)dx}  + \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^1 {\left( {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right)\cos 2n\pi xdx} } }$$
$$\displaystyle{ = \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^1 {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2}\cos 2n\pi x\,dx} } }$$

But $$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^1 {{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)}^2}\cos 2n\pi x\,dx}  = \frac{2}{{{n^2}{\pi ^2}}}} (elementary) and finally \displaystyle{S = \frac{{{\pi ^2}}}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{2}{{{n^3}{\pi ^2}}}}  = \zeta \left( 3 \right)}$$  :)  :)

Answer (score 0):

With completely Fourier ( somewhat similar ) we get the following:

One can easily verify $(\dagger)$ identity
$$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos (2 \pi n x)}{n^2}=\frac{{\rm Li}_2(e^{-2\pi i x})+{\rm Li}_2(e^{2\pi i x})}{2}}$$
Then we have sequentially:
$$\displaystyle{\begin{aligned} 
\int_0^1 \bigg({\rm Li}_2 \left(e^{-2\pi i x} \right)+{\rm Li}_2 \left(e^{2\pi i x} \right) \bigg)\log \Gamma(x) \; {\rm d}x &= 2\int_{0}^{1} \log \Gamma(x) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2 \pi n x}{n^2} \, {\rm d}x\\  
 &= 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \int_{0}^{1}\cos 2 n \pi x \log \Gamma(x) \, {\rm d}x\\  
 &\overset{(*)}{=} 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4n^3} \\  
 &= \frac{\zeta(3)}{2} 
\end{aligned}}$$
$\dagger)$ It is left as an exercise to the reader. Of course, the sum of polylogarithms falls into something elementary, since for example it is true $$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \frac{\pi-x}{2} \quad , \quad x \in (0, 2\pi)}$$ where with proper manipulation and integration we get the formula which does not contain polylogarithms.

(*) These are the Fourier a_n coefficients of the spread $\log \Gamma.$ Namely
$$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1} \cos 2 n \pi x \log \Gamma(x) \, {\rm d}x = \frac{1}{4n}}$$